# Vanilla JS Alternatives to element.getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using getBoundingClientRect() in my application to get the dimensions of an element while the user is dragging an item around. I've been using this and it's been working well; however, I'm beginning to get major performance issues while this calculation is being performed during mouse move. It gets even worse the larger the node is that's being moved. I've used the profiling tools in Chrome and noticed that this function, being wrapped in the mouse move event that gets fired while the user is dragging, is taking a long time (31.4ms per call---scale that to being called every time the mouse moves.) While researching the issue, I came across others who've used it and noticed the performance issues as well (http://dcousineau.com/blog/2013/09/03/high-performance-js-tip/).

What are my alternatives to getBoundingClientRect() in vanilla Javascript (absolutely no jQuery)? My front-end framework is AngularJS 1.5.8, and I've built out the application using components (looking toward migrating our large app to NG2 in the future). Thanks!

Comment: get the initial position of the element on the initial click, no need to recalculate it on every mouse move

Comment: Could you post a minimal code to play around?

Comment: As Karl said in their answer, it doesn't get "more" vanilla. Sure, if you only need some of the values, you could request the individual properties that hold them - but that is likely not gonna be much faster. So your only option to increase performance might be to query the values less often. Look into debouncing/throttling. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/, https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 2):

`Element.getBoundingClientRect()` is "vanilla", although it's part of a [working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-getboundingclientrect) of the specification. To make your code more performant, limit the number of invocations. The link you referred to which mentions similiar performance says just that:

> All calls to get any calculated dimension from the DOM should be cached or avoided.

Comment: Right. So my question is "What are the alternatives (are there alternatives) " to using getBoundingClientRect()? I understand it's vanilla, my question is "What are the alternatives IN vanilla"? The key quote from the article I'm looking at would be this "The problem is WebKit likes to recalculate the layout of the dom pretty much every single time you use something similar to getBoundingClientRect." So what can be done to not have WebKit recalculate the layout of the dom while gettin the data getBoundingClientRect provides?

Comment: You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` and you should - when applicable. If you could provide some sample code we might be able to help you with your specific performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

**!! Following solution doesn't work in combination with CSS3 scale transform** but it's an alternative :

```
function getPosition(elm) {
  var xPos = 0, yPos = 0;

  while(elm) {
    xPos += (elm.offsetLeft - elm.scrollLeft + elm.clientLeft);
    yPos += (elm.offsetTop - elm.scrollTop + elm.clientTop);
    elm = elm.offsetParent;
  }

  return { x: xPos, y: yPos };
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/caryfuk/3b7bb50831421f1873aa)

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a CSS3 scale transform.

Comment: I have been looking for a way to fall back to getBoundingClientRect, but there's no easy way that performs well to see if an element has been transformed. There's getComputedStyle, but that's just as slow (maybe slower) as getBoundingClientRect. There needs to be a `element.transformed` property, or something.